# Excel File protection via xlwt not working for Mac's Number

Tags: excel, python-3.x, password-protection, xlwt

I am using xlwt to write a file to excel and also making it protected using `worksheet.protect`. When I opened that file using MS Excel, protection was there and everything worked perfect it was supposed to be. But when I'm opening that file using Mac's **Number** application and also online via Google Sheets, it is disabling the protection enabled by default automatically. Any help/suggestion ??

Comment: Use equivalent the functions in Google sheets and Apple Numbers - they are not the same applications so you have to write different solutions. I use one of them to get around passwords set in another application...

Comment: Can you suggest some references which can help me ?